AG Grid cell renderer class has instantiation issues
Tried implementing a cell renderer class to include a <div> element in one of the cells (basically to act as a legend for an attached donut chart representing the grid.)
I've defined the class within the same React component, (tried placing it both inside and outside the function), but I get a browser-side error class constructors must be invoked with 'new'. I've followed the docs one to one on the instruction so I don't understand where I'm going wrong. I've also tried instantiating the same before rendering it but to no avail.
Here's the code for the class and the renderer:
class GroupColourRenderer {
  colorDiv;
  colorIndex = 0;
  colorArray = ['#FF0000', '#01a698', '#f5a824'];
  init(params) {
    this.colorDiv = document.createElement('div');
    this.colorDiv.setAttribute(
      'style',
      `width: 3px; height: 3px; border-radius: 9999px; background-color: ${this.colorArray[this.colorIndex % this.colorArray.length]}`,
    );
    this.colorIndex++;
  }

  getColorDiv() {
    return this.colorDiv;
  }
  refresh(params) {
    return false;
  }
}

and the columnDefs for the grid:
const columnDefs = [
  {
    headerName: 'Group',
    field: 'groupingName',
    flex: 2,
    cellRenderer: GroupColourRenderer,
  },
  { headerName: 'Count', field: 'groupingCount', flex: 1 },
];

Any help would be appreciated :)
